# angular get controller constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to factor out some common functionality between some of my controllers into a parent controller. I'd like to do this using some sort of inheritance, instead of some sort of service. 
All examples using the `$injector.invoke` function rely on the parent's constructor function being in scope.
Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/kva82QyytKQfOafGiVxL?p=preview.

Since I have all my controllers in separate files, I'd like to do something like this:

The parent controller has its own module:

```
angular.module('app.parent').controller('ParentCtrl', function() {
    this.someMethodProvidedbyParent = ....
});
```

The child controller extends `ParentCtrl` using `$injector.invoke`. How to get `ParentCtrl`?

```
angular.module('app.parent.child').controller('ChildCtrl', function($injector) {

    // Somehow need to get ParentCtrl from the angular module 'app.parent'
    $injector.invoke(ParentCtrl, this, {});
});
```

I assume I could just place ParentCtrl in some object on the global scope, but I'd rather use the angular module system.

Comment: you could use `$controller` dependancy, `$controller('ParentCtrl', {this: this});` should work in child controller

Comment: Didn't work when I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it with instantiating the parent controller and then using `angular.extend` like so:

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('ParentCtrl'));

  // Overriding methods here (after extending `this`)
});
```

Properties from the parent are copied to `this`.

Comment: Nice appoarch.. +1 didn't thought about it